# Submitting same URL (with different content) to Google in different languages

Tags: browser, language, web, search-indexing

I've submitted my web page to Google using the webmaster tools and after a few weeks I've correctly seen it in search results. Now the question: my page uses language detection via Apache wizardry so that the page is served in the relevant language based on the browser settings (via AddLanguage and LanguagePriority for those who want to know...) and it can be retrieved by simply using `host/folder/page` while the actual page sits at `host/folder/page.<lang>.html` and I obviously want to index the simpler URL instead of the actual html one because that way it's "independent" of language.

How do I submit the same URL to different Google countries or is the "generic" (English) crawler smart enough to index it by automatically using multiple language settings when retrieving the page?

You can test the page at:
http://www.nicealias.com/articles/focus_on_renewables.en.html
by replacing .en with .fr and by optionally removing .html and the language extension too
(as in http://www.nicealias.com/articles/focus_on_renewables)

Comment: @Rahul2001 - This doesn't belong here nor at Serverfault.  If we were to migrate it to Serverfault the migration would be likely rejected.

Comment: This question belongs on webmasters.se.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: What others said. I'd start from here ([hreflang and canonical](https://yoast.com/hreflang-ultimate-guide/)) and SE Webmasters.

Comment: Just make sure that all other pages have the no-index no-follow in the meta tags and you should be good.

Comment: in that case, can some admin migrate my question to webmasters? thanks